# Integration of inverse cdf

Tags: integration, statistics

I fail to understand the following integration substitution:
$$ \frac{1}\alpha \int_0^\alpha F^{-1}(1 - u) du = \frac{1}\alpha \int_{F^{-1}(1 - \alpha)}^\infty v*f(v)dv $$

Knowing that:

- F is a continuous, monotonous and increasing cumulated distribution function.
- The substitution used is : $F^{-1}(1-u) = v$

When defining the substitution proof as follow:

$$ \int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x) dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(j)dj $$

If here our substitution argument is $F^{-1}(1-u) = v = g(x)$, then we should have $g'(x) = f(v)$ and I fail to find this back.

To add some context, this substitution is used to prove the formula for expected shortfall in the book: Stochastiche Risikomodellierung und statistische Methoden from Torsten Becker, Richard Herrmann, Viktor Sandor, Domini Schäfer and Ulrich Wellisch.

Great thanks in advance and my best wishes for 2024 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=F^{-1}(1-u)$. Using the formula for the dervative of an inverse function we get $dv=-\frac 1 {F'(F^{-1}(1-u))} du=-\frac 1 {F'(v)}du$. Hence, $du=-f(v)dv$. So the left side becomes $\frac 1 {\alpha}\int_{F^{-1}(1-\alpha)}^{\infty} vf(v)dv$. Note that there is a typo on the right side. [Lower limit of the integral is wrong].

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply ! It is very clear. Link to [inverse function derivation](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Calculus_(OpenStax)/03%3A_Derivatives/3.07%3A_Derivatives_of_Inverse_Functions#:~:text=The%20Derivative%20of%20an%20Inverse%20Function,-We%20begin%20by&text=(f%E2%88%921)%E2%80%B2(a)%3Dpq.&text=f%E2%80%B2(f%E2%88%921(,a))%3Dqp.). The typo within the question is now corrected.